# Diff between sourceurl and linkurl and how to display image attachments for different features in 1 layer

Tags: javascript, mapping, arcgis

What is the difference between the sourceURL and linkURL?

Also, I have a layer that has multiple features.  Each feature has an attached image.  How would I set up the popup to find and show the attachment unique to the feature?

```
  //define a popup template
        var popupTemplate = new esri.dijit.PopupTemplate({
          title: "{BUILDING}",
          fieldInfos: [
          {fieldName: "FLOOR", visible: true, label:"Floor:"},
          {fieldName: "BUILDING", visible: true, label:"Building Name:"},
          {fieldName: "CAMERA", visible: false, label:"Camera:"},
          ],
          mediaInfos: [{
            "title": "Image:",
            "caption": "",
            "type": "image",
            "value": {
              "sourceURL": "http://gis.aoscloud.net/aosmaps/rest/services/Test/Test/FeatureServer/0/1025/attachments/1201",
              }
          }],
        });

        //create a feature layer based on the feature collection
        var featureLayer = new esri.layers.FeatureLayer("http://gis.aoscloud.net/aosmaps/rest/services/Test/Test/MapServer/0", {
          mode: esri.layers.FeatureLayer.MODE_SNAPSHOT,
          infoTemplate: popupTemplate,
          outFields: ["*"],
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The source url of the image and the url of a related link. Clicking on the image opens the `linkUrl`. It's optional.

Comment: When linking to the image then, you would put a url in for the sourceurl such as...www.url.com/rest/services/featureserver/ ?

Comment: @user2733678 sorry, don't know what you mean.

Comment: I guess I'm just confused on what you put in place of the {link} for the sourceURL then....

Comment: @user2733678 I see. Yes, it's an URL like in your comment. The address of the image.

Comment: Here's the issue with this.  When I put the link to the image in the sourceURL, it makes every feature in my web map have that image.  Is there a generic link where it will automatically find the correct image attachment?

Comment: @user2733678 Only if you use one template. This is beyond the scope of your question. Please edit it or create a new one and add an example of what you are doing.

Comment: Alrighty, I edited my original statement.  I'm confused when you say use one template?  Shouldn't the code be able to pull the image that's stored in the ArcSDE when you select a feature on the map and display it the popup?

Comment: My test application is unsecured at the moment also.  gis.aoscloud.net/test/s3.html

Comment: @user2733678 The thing is that there could be more than one attachment. So I'm not sure your approach can work at all. You could try to replace the end of the url, the "1201" with something like "{attachmentInfos[0].id}". If it works then it should be replaced with the id of the first attachment of the selected feature. That's as far as I can help you.